# Grammatik in "bestaunt zu werden und befragt"

Tags: grammar, passive

Aus *Der Spiegel*:

> Später hat mir einer der beiden Vettern erzählt, wie seltsam für sie diese erste Reise ins Grauland war, das mit ihrem Leben am Rhein so wenig zu tun hatte. Die Mauer war für sie bis dato ein Ding aus dem Fernsehen, mehr nicht. Und er erzählte, wie unangenehm es war, **bestaunt zu werden und befragt.** Und wie ihnen von ihren Eltern vorher eingeschärft worden war, an der Grenze nichts zu sagen, damit es ja keinen Ärger gab.

Sollte es hier nicht

> bestaunt und befragt zu werden

sein? Der Person war es unangenehm, dass er bestaunt und befragt wurde.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich stimme Matthias zu, dass der Satz korrekt aber stilistisch ungewöhnlich ist.

Für mich klingt diese Konstruktion nach einem poetischen Versuch, einen bestimmten Sprechrhythmus in der indirekten Rede wiederzugeben. Sprachmelodisch ist der Satz dadurch fließender mit dem folgenden verbunden.

> Es war unangenehm, bestaunt zu werden und befragt.

erzeugt eine gedankliche Trennung zwischen den beiden Teilen ein. Der Satz ist nach "bestaunt zu werden" eigentlich beendet, der Gedanke an das Befragtwerden folgt erst ein wenig später. Die folgenden Ratschläge der Eltern beziehen sich nur auf den zweiten Teil. Es ergibt sich der Eindruck, dass man den Sprecher beim Bilden seiner Assoziationsketten sehr unmittelbar beobachtet.

> Es war unangenehm, bestaunt und befragt zu werden.

würde diese beiden Erfahrungen zu einer Einheit machen und etwas stärker vom folgenden Satz abgrenzen.

Answer (score 3):

Der Satz ist korrekt, aber stilistisch ungewöhnlich - oder, um es wertender zu sagen, etwas gespreizt.

Ich sehe zwei Möglichkeiten der Erklärung. Die erste ist die sogenannte [**Zusammenziehung**](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Ordnung/Zusammenziehung.html). Dabei wird in zwei Teilsätzen ein identisches Satzglied weggelassen (hier: das Hilfsverb werden). Das trifft auf jeden Fall zu auf das von Dir erwartete

> bestaunt und befragt zu werden,

das ja eigentlich vollständig heißen müsste

> bestaunt zu werden und befragt zu werden.

Aber ich sehe keinen Grund, warum man nicht auch das zweite "zu werden" weglassen dürfte statt des ersten - es ist in dieser Konstellation nur einfach ungewöhnlich, es zu tun.

Die angegebene canoo-Seite führt z.B. an

> Sie wurden befördert und wir [wurden] entlassen.

In diesem Beispiel hat man keine Wahl (man kann nur das zweite "wurden" weglassen), aber wenn man einen Nebensatz daraus macht (bzw. zwei mit "und" verbundene), so geht beides:

> Wir erfuhren, dass sie befördert wurden und wir entlassen.
>   Wir erfuhren, dass sie befördert und wir entlassen wurden. (gebräuchlicher)

Die andere Erklärung wäre das Stilmittel der [**Ellipse**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)). Dabei wird bewusst ein Satzteil weggelassen, der sich aber aus dem verbliebenen Rest rekonstruieren lässt.

Leider habe ich nichts (für mich Verwertbares) dazu gefunden, inwieweit Zusammenziehung und Ellipse gegeneinander abgegrenzt werden oder ob die Zusammenziehung gar als Spezialfall der Ellipse angesehen werden kann. Vielleicht wird das ja hier noch jemand anders klarstellen können.

Answer (score 2):

Für mich fühlt es sich wie ein besetztes Nachfeld an. Eine Sache wird hinter das finale Verb geschoben. Ich habe das Gefühl, das gerade Politiker die Tendenz zeigen, auch kurze Konstituenten nach hinten zu verschieben.

> Wir müssen uns kümmern um diese Probleme.

Das Phänomen ist aber keineswegs neu. Deutsch war früher ja viel wilder, was die Satzordnung angeht. Daher klingt es manchmal auch ein kleines bisschen poetisch.
Natürlich kann es theoretisch auch eine Ellipse sein, aber es wäre definitiv natürlicher, das erste "werden" wegzulassen. Das zweite wäre schon ein sehr bewusster Konventionsbruch.
Eine Ausklammerung ins Nachfeld ist natürlicher, und daher naheliegender.

Struktur:

> ... bestaunt zu [finales verb: werden] [Nachfeld: und befragt].

vs.

> ... bestaunt zu werden und befragt [Auslassung: zu werden][Nachfeld: leer]